# Is it possible to read one line of a MySQL table as a string in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was wondering if it was possible to read a whole row of a MySQL table as a string, rather than having to split it up into separate types like different Strings, ints, booleans etc.

The reason I'm asking is that this is for a shared package and so obviously each table has different columns and data types. It would be much easier if I could read the line as a string and then pass it off to the individual class dealing with the data from that table, rather than split it up into the different data types. Obviously this would only be feasible if looking for only a single row in the table

```
private String row;

public String getRow(){
   return row;
}

public String getRowFromTable(){
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/t", "", "");

   Statement st = con.createStatement();
   String sql = ("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1;");
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
   row = rs.getRow(); // Basically, is this part possible?
   con.close();
}
```

Comment: "*as a string?*" Did you mean an entire row as a string? then why don't you just concatenate the contents of all columns of that row after fetching that row from the database? Fetching a row with the **mapped** data types intact is feasible, if you use an ORM framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe that it's possible in quite the way you're suggesting. However, thinking outside of the box:

- You can concatenate all your columns into one string using SQL string concatenation.
- You can use the [result set's meta data](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29) to create a framework that will do type conversions and inject data into your classes depending on type.

Of course, a better recommendation would probably be to use an ORM framework like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MySQL CONCAT function to concatenate all the columns, but the idea is dubious at best.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the structure of table `posts` it doesn't actually make sense to read whole record as a string and then pass it to some parser. It would be much more efficient to create new instance of some kind of `Post` class (related to `posts` table), write simple marshaller method and feed it with data, e.g:

```
try (
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1");
) {
    return rs.next() ? this.marshall(rs, new Post()) : null;
}
catch (SQLException x) {
    x.printStacktrace();
}
```

And you can write `marshall` method like this:

```
private Post marshall(ResultSet rs, Post post) {
    post.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    post.setSubject(rs.getString("subject"));
    // Fill other fields as needed.
    return post;
}
```

But in fact you can get the result as a string (if you insist to use `*` in SQL query), but you need to use `MetaData` for it:

```
try (
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1");
) {
    if (!rs.next()) {
        return null;
    }
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1, l = md.getColumnCount(); i <= l; i++) {
        sb.append(rs.getString(i));
        if (i < l) {
            sb.append(';');
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
catch (SQLException x) {
    x.printStacktrace();
}
```

Note: avoid `;` at the end of SQL queries in JDBC. Of course you need semicolon to separate queries if there are more of them in one string, but generally `;` shouldn't be the last character in JDBC query string.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it in one step, you would have to create that string yourself. I think there are better generic representations than a single string per row, like a list/array of objects or strings, one per column, or as a map.

NOT TESTED CODE:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 1;");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

/* Choose your representation */
String asString = "";
List<String> asStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, String> asMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
    Object c = rs.getObject(i+1);
    asStringColumn = c == null ? null : c.toString();
    asString += ";" + asStringColumn;
    asStringList.add(asStringColumn);
    asMap.put(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i+1), asStringColumn);
}
```